# JTS.orthodromicDistance incorrectly calculate the equatorial radius of the earth

Tags: java, jts

JTS.orthodromicDistance(new Coordinate(0,0), new Coordinate(180,0), DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84) * 2 is equal to 40075016 but must be equal to 6378000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get what you asked for. Your formula calculates the circumference, which is `2*pi*radius`.

The radius is `circumference / (2*pi)`, indeed about 6378000.